# changing permissions for a network share takes longer on win2008  than on win2003, why is that?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, permissions, network-share

Given a network share accessible for "everyone" in the domain, containing several 1000 files and folders

When I change permissions for this share from read/write to only read (or vice versa) on windows 2003, the change takes effect instantly.

When I do the same on a share on Windows 2008, the dialog stays open for a long time before closing when I click on OK, and the server appears to be accessing a lot of files.

What is the reason for this delay? Does Windows 2008 also change ntfs permissions for all files inside the share? If so, why doesn't win2003 have to do that?

I do not mind the delay, after all I do not have to change this stuff very often, but I am curious.
What are the differences between 2003 and 2008 in this regard?

Comment: Is the hardware 100% the same?

Comment: no, but the win2008 server has the newer and faster hardware, and the files have just been copied to the new server. The fact that the win2003 server returns *instantly* makes me believe that this is not merely due to a difference in speed

Comment: Are you sure you aren't changing NTFS permissions somewhere when you edit the permissions? I ran several tests on different 2008 servers with 10,000+ file/folders and don't see the same issue when changing just share permissions.

Comment: I suspect you are right in your suspicion because I have a similar experience. See my question [Why does Windows share permissions change file permissions?](http://serverfault.com/questions/551722/why-does-windows-share-permissions-change-file-permissions)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you're using the Simple Sharing wizard on Server 2008+ which also transparently changes NTFS permissions. This is why you should always used "Advanced" mode sharing, as it does not try and "help" you.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't experienced this myself.

I'm inclined to suspect network issues, or one of the many bugs in the Windows file system redirector that have inevitably surfaced over time.

You may want to perform two comparison packet captures of a Windows 2003 and 2008 machine.  That would probably reveal the differences.  If using NetMon, you can filter the saved capture display on the letters SMB.